# how to create log file under project base directory using log4j2

Tags: log4j, log4j2, appender, rollingfileappender

I wanted to create log file in my maven project under project base directory.I am using log4j2 framework kept the log4j2.xml file under src/mian/resources folder. below is the file. please update what is wrong in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
   packages="com.viveo.rtcc.common.client.traces" status="WARN">
       <Properties>
             <Property name="log-path">appLogs</Property>

       </Properties>
       <Appenders>
                 <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
                    <!-- <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} 
                      - %msg%n"/> -->
                    <PatternLayout pattern="[ %d ] %p %t %c : %m%n" />
            </Console>
            <RollingFile name="rollingFileAppender"
                fileName="${log-path}/reLog.log"
                filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout>
                          <Pattern>%d [%t] %p %c - %m%n</Pattern>
                    </PatternLayout>
                    <Policies>
                          <!-- <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy /> <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy /> -->
                          <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10000 KB" />
                    </Policies>
                    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
             </RollingFile>
             <MessageAreaAppender name="MessageAreaAppender" />
       </Appenders>
       <Loggers>
             <!-- <Root level="DEBUG"> <AppenderRef ref="RollingFileAppender" /> <AppenderRef 
                ref="Console" />
 <AppenderRef ref="MessageAreaAppender" /> </Root> -->


             <Logger name="com.yourloggername" level="debug"
                additivity="false">
                    <!-- <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> -->
                    <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender" />
             </Logger>

             <Root level="info">
                    <!-- <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> -->
                    <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender" />
             </Root>
       </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I see wrong in your configuration:

1. Maven builds run with the working directory set to the root directory of the project. Any files creates will be respective of that. In your configuration that means it would create the logs in a directory named appLogs. This is a poor practice in Maven builds. You should change it to target/applogs.
2. Your filePattern contains %d{dMM-dd-yy} but none of your triggering policies are time based. Without a time-based trigger I would expect that time to never changed while the application is running.

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately none of the solutions worked out. here is the updated log4j2.xml after changing.  i changed xml as below                                                                     <Properties>
               <Property name="log-path">target/appLogs</Property>
</Properties>
<Policies>
               <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10000 KB" />
               <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</Policies>

Comment: It just occurred to me that you put the log4j2.xml in the src/main/resources directory. When I first read this I assumed you were trying to use it for testing. Reading it again I am not sure why I thought that. If you are trying to package the log4j2.xml with your application then the original log path of applogs would have created that directory and written the log files there. That directory would be created in whatever directory you started your application from. If that isn't working.add status="DEBUG" to the Configuration element and see if that provides help.